# How do I scan text into a string within a function?

Tags: c, function, scanf

So I have to scan text from a file into an array, but I am only allowed to use scanf() to achieve this. In the file, there are 22 lines and the longest line is 455 characters long.  When I compile, I get various warnings.  I have been trying to find a solution but nothings seems to help my list of warnings and errors.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define NUM_ROWS 22
#define LENGTH_OF_LONGEST_LINE 455
void textInit(char array[]);

int main(void) {
   char patty [NUM_ROWS][LENGTH_OF_LONGEST_LINE];

   textInit(patty[NUM_ROWS][LENGTH_OF_LONGEST_LINE]);


   return 0;
}


void textInit(char array[]) {

   int x = 0;

   for (x = 0; x < 22; ++x) {
      scanf("%455s", array[x]);
   }
   return;
}
```

The errors I recieve are:

```
StPat.c: In function âmainâ:
StPat.c:14:4: warning: passing argument 1 of âtextInitâ makes pointer from 
integer without a cast [enabled by default]
    textInit(patty[NUM_ROWS][LENGTH_OF_LONGEST_LINE]);
    ^
StPat.c:9:6: note: expected âchar *â but argument is of type âcharâ
     void textInit(char array[]);
     ^
StPat.c: In function âtextInitâ:
StPat.c:26:7: warning: format â%sâ expects argument of type âchar *â, but
argument 2 has type âintâ [-Wformat=]
       scanf("%455s", array[x]);
```

Comment: like [this](http://ideone.com/epXtBr)

Comment: You should post it here for a single line read example.

Comment: Don't vandalize your questions.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the user removed the actual code

Comment: @user3629249 Double-check that, please.

Answer (score 1):

`LENGTH_OF_LONGEST_LINE` should be `456` to allow space for the `\0` terminator.

The body of the function `textInit()` expects a 2d array, but the function signature only indicates an array of `char`s. You should also pass the dimensions of the array to the function, rather than rely on global constants.

When you call the `textInit()` function, you are attempting to pass a `char` instead of a 2d array (really, a 2d array name in a function call decays to a pointer to an array). The attempted access is out of bounds.

Finally, in the `textInit()` function, avoid using magic numbers, as you have in the loop in this function. And you should use `size_t` for array indices, as it is an unsigned integer type guaranteed to hold any array index.

Here is a modified version of your code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define NUM_ROWS 22
#define LENGTH_OF_LONGEST_LINE 456

void textInit(char array[][LENGTH_OF_LONGEST_LINE], size_t rows, size_t cols);

int main(void)
{
   char patty [NUM_ROWS][LENGTH_OF_LONGEST_LINE];

   textInit(patty, NUM_ROWS, LENGTH_OF_LONGEST_LINE);

   return 0;
}


void textInit(char array[][LENGTH_OF_LONGEST_LINE], size_t rows, size_t cols)
{
    size_t x = 0;

   for (x = 0; x < rows; ++x) {
      scanf("%455s", array[x]);
   }

   return;
}
```

Comment: Or, `for (x = 0; x < rows;) if (scanf ("%455[^\n]%*c", array[x]) == 1) x++;` Or, better yet use `fgets` and test for and strip the trailing `'\n'`...

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the `nul-byte` catch by Mr. Bowling, you can also make use of `fgets` to take the input. If you would like to init the entire array, you can pass an *array of pointers to type char `LENGTH_OF_LONGEST_LINE`* and initialize the entire array at once. For example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

enum { MAXROWS = 22, MAXLINE = 456 };

size_t textinit (char (*a)[MAXLINE], size_t rows, size_t cols);

int main(void) {

    size_t i, n;
    char patty [MAXROWS][MAXLINE] = {""};

    n = textinit (patty, MAXROWS, MAXLINE);

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        printf (" string[%2zu] : %s\n", i, patty[i]);

    return 0;
}


size_t textinit (char (*a)[MAXLINE], size_t rows, size_t cols)
{
    size_t n = 0;

    while (n < rows && fgets (a[n], cols, stdin)) 
    {
        size_t len = strlen (a[n]); /* get lenght */
        if (a[n][len - 1] == '\n')  /* check for '\n' */
            a[n][--len] = 0;        /* overwrite with nul-byte */
        n++;
    }

    return n;   /* return number of strings read */
}
```

Note, that `fgets` reads up to and including the `'\n'`, so you remove the newline by getting the length of each string read, then testing for, and overwriting the `'\n'` with a *nul-terminating* character `0` (or the equivalent `'\0'`).

Also note, if you are on windows, replace `size_t` with `unsigned` and `%2zu` in the `printf` with simply `%2u`.

Comment: "_if you are on windows, replace `size_t` with `unsigned` and `%2zu` in the `printf` with simply `%2u`_" - Why? Doesn't windows support `size_t`?

Comment: It depends on the compiler. Earlier versions of windows compilers do not implement the `'z'` prefix for `size_t` designation (they have `size_t` of course, but they use a plain `%u` to print the type) I've seen this with folks trying to compile with Codeblocks, etc..